# Decrypt s3 file unloaded using unload command with symmetric key encryption

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, aes

I tried decrypting a file from s3 which was uploaded by unload command from redshift with AES symmetric key encryption.
If we use the AWS java sdk to download with aes key given to the s3 client it works fine.But if we try to manually decrypt it after downloading the file it gives `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded` error.

The reason for manually decrypting the file is i want to decrypt the file using node.js and as far as i know there is no sdk in node that can do this directly.

Node.js code that i tried:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

var algorithm = 'aes256';
var inputEncoding = 'hex';
var outputEncoding = 'utf-8';

var key = "symmetric key base 64"; //prod

var data = fs.readFileSync('/tmp/files/myfile');
console.log(data);

var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm,key);

var deciphered = decipher.update(data, inputEncoding, outputEncoding);
console.log(deciphered);
deciphered += decipher.final(outputEncoding); 
console.log(deciphered);
```

When i try this i get this error: `Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt`

Answer (score 1):

So Redshift uses the envelope encryption the same way as the AWS SDK uses envelope encryption to store files on S3. So in order to decrypt the file you should:

1. Get the encrypted data key and the iv from the S3 object metadata (x-amz-meta-x-amz-key and x-amz-meta-x-amz-iv respectively)
2. Decrypt that x-amz-meta-x-amz-key value using your symmetric key using AES256 ECB mode => var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('AES-128-ECB',key,'');
3. Then decrypt '0000_part_00' using AES256 CBC mode with iv set to iv from step1 and the key set to the result of step 2. => crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv)
4. Remove padding (should be able to use cipher.setAutoPadding(true) if [Node.js Crypo, what's the default padding for AES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701311/node-js-crypo-whats-the-default-padding-for-aes) is correct)

I haven't coded it in nodejs but I have successfully used these steps in Python
[step2](https://github.com/pvbouwel/redshift-manifest-tools/blob/master/util/file_cryptor.py#L31-L43) [step 3+4](https://github.com/pvbouwel/redshift-manifest-tools/blob/master/util/file_cryptor.py#L109-L121)