# AES-CBC decryption node.js vs. forge digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes

I want to decrypt something with the decipher that is part of node.js but I get an error message. If I use forge on the same input data, then the data can be decrypted. What am I doing wrong in the nodeDecrypt function?

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const keyHash = "b6db3d66f4f8bd82aea61576e221f23634bb7c585340a8a42140701f5a468e04"
const encryptedB64 = "cHIaTs0vA6phV8jyT3X78cTSrUnLeBwbAqstVBAl7kl4uV+4oGQFVgsChW8lfw4QOyECkZAay7c0rDi816T9ZA==";

const encryptedBuffer = Buffer.from(encryptedB64, 'base64');

var userKey = Buffer.from(keyHash, 'hex');

const forge = require('node-forge');


function nodeDecrypt(encrypted, key) {
    const iv = encrypted.slice(0, 16);
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);

    encrypted = encrypted.slice(16);

    var decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted);

    console.log(decrypted.toString());
    try {
        decrypted += decipher.final();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    
    return decrypted;
}

function forgeDecrypt(encrypted, key) {
    const encoding = 'latin1';
    key = key.toString(encoding);
    initVal = encrypted.toString(encoding).substring(0, 16);
    encrypted = encrypted.toString(encoding).substring(16);
    var decipher = forge.cipher.createDecipher('AES-CBC', key);
    decipher.start({ iv: initVal });
    decipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(encrypted));
    var result = decipher.finish();
    return decipher.output.getBytes();
}
var decrypted;

decrypted = nodeDecrypt(encryptedBuffer, userKey);
console.log(decrypted.toString());

decrypted = forgeDecrypt(encryptedBuffer, userKey);
console.log(decrypted.toString());
```

Output

```
1a24989e-75d1-4631-8210-b17bb5e6
decryptor.js:26
Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at Decipheriv.final (<node_internals>/internal/crypto/cipher.js:174:29)
...
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {library: 'digital envelope routines', function: 'EVP_DecryptFinal_ex', reason: 'bad decrypt', code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_BAD_

1a24989e-75d1-4631-8210-b17bb5e6

1a24989e-75d1-4631-8210-b17bb5e6a2a1
```

This is with nodes.js version 14.15.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CBC mode generally (including this case) needs padding, and your encryption uses padding where only the last byte specifies the length and the other bytes are random. node-forge evidently accepts this, but nodejs builtin `crypto` uses OpenSSL (specifically the `EVP_Decrypt*` API, as you can see in the error message) which [by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701311/node-js-crypto-whats-the-default-padding-for-aes) implements [PKCS5/7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) where *all* bytes must contain the length.

OpenSSL, and `crypto`, does have an option to not do any padding and unpadding at all, leaving you to do it yourself. You can use that option here as follows:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const keyHash = "b6db3d66f4f8bd82aea61576e221f23634bb7c585340a8a42140701f5a468e04"
const encryptedB64 = "cHIaTs0vA6phV8jyT3X78cTSrUnLeBwbAqstVBAl7kl4uV+4oGQFVgsChW8lfw4QOyECkZAay7c0rDi816T9ZA==";

const encryptedBuffer = Buffer.from(encryptedB64, 'base64');

var userKey = Buffer.from(keyHash, 'hex');

const forge = require('node-forge');


function nodeDecrypt(encrypted, key) {
    const iv = encrypted.slice(0, 16);
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
    decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
    encrypted = encrypted.slice(16);
    var decrypted = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(encrypted),decipher.final()]);
    var padlen = decrypted[decrypted.length-1];    
    return decrypted.slice(0,decrypted.length-padlen);
}

function forgeDecrypt(encrypted, key) {
    const encoding = 'latin1';
    key = key.toString(encoding);
    initVal = encrypted.toString(encoding).substring(0, 16);
    encrypted = encrypted.toString(encoding).substring(16);
    var decipher = forge.cipher.createDecipher('AES-CBC', key);
    decipher.start({ iv: initVal });
    decipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(encrypted));
    var result = decipher.finish();
    return decipher.output.getBytes();
}
var decrypted;

decrypted = nodeDecrypt(encryptedBuffer, userKey);
console.log(decrypted.toString());

decrypted = forgeDecrypt(encryptedBuffer, userKey);
console.log(decrypted.toString());
```